# Single process with multiple dbus services

Tags: dbus

I am trying understand dbus IPC, please help me on this.

If we need to communicate through dbus, the process needs to get the system/session bus and then request a name for service and then register its objects/interfaces. if my understanding is right, Is it allowed to have multiple services from a single process? If it is allowed, how does the dbus differentiates between the objects (nodes) between the services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there is one connection to the daemon per process instance, and each instance will get its own unique ID. (unique busname). There also is a well-known busname, which is what application supplies, so you can poll a specific well-known bus and don't have to address the applications by unique names.

For example, a well-known name is org.bluez, and a unique name currently on my system is 1.46

You could theoretically create multiple buses from a single proces, but I don't really see the point.

Reference material: https://pythonhosted.org/txdbus/dbus_overview.html